# WordPress ACF user fields not pulling through

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have set up custom fields (ACF) for authors on WordPress.
The fields have been completed, however they are not pulling through the content. Please can someone tell me where I am going wrong.

The user data from the wp_query is displaying as it should, but not the ACFs.

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $author = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

    // author id
    $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');

    // vars
    $test = get_field('test', 'user_'. $author_id ); ?>

    // None of these work   
    <?= ( $test )? '<h1>' . $test .'</h1>' : '';?>
    <h1><?php echo $test; ?></h1>

    // This works
    <h1 class="page-title page-title__author"><?php echo $author->display_name; ?></h1>
```

Comment: Seems correct. Have you printed the result of author_id to check if it is correct?

Comment: can you print $author_id here?